# Looking for flexible firewall/NAT software to mimic SOHO gateways

Tags: firewall, nat

II am working on a project where I need to create a virtual machine that acts like a home gateway, so I am looking for the firewall/NAT that is most flexible. My hope would be that I could give some configurations that would make the VM act like some of the gateways typically installed in homes and small offices.

Has anyone tried this before? Which software might be best for this? I can use any OS, so it could be pf, pfSense, iptables, ipfw, ipfilter, or even something more obscure. Any clues are appreciated.

Comment: DD-WRT can install on x86.  Your question is likely to be closed though since Product, service, or learning material recommendations is off-topic per the FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

Install smoothwall into a VM running on the hypervisor of your preference. You will need a lot of NICs or if you use switching that supports vlan tagging you can make do with less.